# AngularJS using $resource

Tags: angularjs, service, callback, resources, controllers

I have an issue, i use my service that has GET and POST method. I try to update an select component on view. So when i try to add a new item, and click on button, which trigger a POST of new object, and what i want is to recieve updated list with my GET method, but it doesn't work. In only works if i refresh the page. I guess there is something wrong with callback

Here is the code i use:

Controller

```
$scope.addSubject = function(){
    var newSubject = {"subjectName" : $scope.subjectType};
    InterpelationSubjectFactory.create(newSubject);
    /* Calling query method to update subjectType list */
    InterpelationSubjectFactory.query(function(response){
      $scope.subjectTypes =  response;
    });
    console.log($scope.subjectTypes);
    //$scope.selectedSubjectType =  $scope.subjectType;
    $scope.hideSubjectForm = true;
    $scope.subjectType = '';
    /*console.log(newSubject);*/
  }
```

Service

```
services.factory('InterpelationSubjectFactory', function($resource){ 
return $resource(baseUrl + '/subjectTypes', {}, {
   query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
   create: { method: 'POST'}
 })
});
```

Can please someone point me where i did wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the callback, you only have the one in case of success. Can you please add the one that handles error and display the error message? That should give us a clue.

```
InterpelationSubjectFactory.query(function(response){
    // success handler
    $scope.subjectTypes =  response;
}, function(error) {
    // error handler
    console.log("Error InterpelationSubjectFactory.query: " + JSON.stringify(error));
}
);
```

Please share the error message.